# phonegap 1st application replaced android when install 2nd application

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

i had developed 2 android native app using `HTML5 with jquery mobile framework`, at last i used `Phonegap build` features for build my app file `apk`, it's working nice..

my questions is first i had install my first application my Samsung Galaxy S3 device its working fine, but when i instal my second application to same device its saying **"this application you are installing will replace another application"**, why like this.? this two applications are completely different style, size, etc... but still when instal second application first application replaced... phonegap `config.xml` have to add any extra lines for ignore this problems..??

this is my `config.xml` file for 1st application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.q8scool"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>Q8Scool</name>

    <description>
        Q8Scool is a free app for teachers and students, a new level online classroom...
    </description>

    <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
        Gates Business Solutions
    </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="phonegap-version"           value="2.3.0" />          <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="14" />             <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
</widget>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with a `PhoneGap`, but it looks like both of your applications have the same package name. Try to change `id = "com.phonegap.q8scool"` for one of the apps.

Comment: @vmironov  thank you so much, its working, great. i tried these changes, now its working for me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer for my question from one of above comment.
just use different `id` for each applications,

above example: `id = "com.phonegap.q8scool"` and `id = "com.phonegap.othername"`